# Typescript Class Reference

Tags: typescript, inheritance

Flow has the concept that you can write the following type definition to refer to a class that inherits from another class:

`function getHouseClass(): Class<House> {}`

This refers to the class, not an instance of the class.

Is there a similar concept in Typescript?
`Class<House>` apparently doesn't work in TS.

Thanks!

Comment: doesn't the typeof operator do this?

Comment: That is indeed right! I tried it, works wonderfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think @toskv is correct. If you look at [this](https://github.com/niieani/typescript-vs-flowtype) comparison between the two (below 'Accessing the type of a Class' headline):

**Flow**

```
class Test {};
type TestType = Class<Test>;
// This should be equivalent to (if you can confirm, please send a PR):
type TestType = typeof Test;
```

**TypeScript**

```
class Test {};
type TestType = typeof Test;
```

The following should then be the same:

```
function getHouseClass(): typeof House { return House; }
```